# Запрос к базе в фреймворке CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Недавно начал работать с CakePHP
Пытаюсь сделать запрос к базе, создал `TestsController.php`
Написал в нем

```
<?php
class TestsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $user_tasks=$this->Notes->find('all');
        $this->set(compact(user_tasks));
    }
}
```

Таблица `Notes` существует, и она не пустая,
На при заходе на страницу, на которой я вывожу `$user_tasks`, выдает ошибку

> Call to a member function `find()` on `null`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где допустил ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake загружает модель по умолчанию для контроллера на основании имени контроллера. Так например, для контроллера `NotesController` он загрузит модель `Notes`, и она станет доступна через `$this->Notes`. В вашем случае имя контроллера `Test` поэтому он пытается автоматически загрузить модель `Tests`. А вот про модель `Notes` он не знает ничего, поэтому вам следует сделать это вручную.

*Вариант 1.*

```
 $this->loadModel('Notes');
```

после чего можете обращаться к автоматическому свойству `$this->Notes`

*Вариант 2.*

```
$nt = TableRegistry::get('Notes');
$nt->find()->...
```

со вторым вариантом работать проще, дак и в документации чаще используется именно такой подход.

И да, лучше сразу вызывать `->toList()`, `toArray()`, `first()` и т.п. методы, ибо именно при таком вызове выполняется сам запрос к БД. А значит можно перехватить ошибки выполнения, в противном случае запрос будет выполнен в шаблоне. Есть обратный бонус, можно состряпать запросы, которые могут не быть выполнены вовсе, то есть представление будет определять, стоит ли делать выборку.

зы: `compact('user_tasks')` пропущены кавычки, метод `compact` принимает имя(имена) переменной. Вообще если переменная только одна, или их мало, то проще сделать `$this->set('items', $items)`. Код-то ваш работает, но если посмотрите лог, то там будет `Notice` про неопределенное имя константы `user_tasks`

Comment: Вот так ответ. Спасибо огромное, очень помогли!